# GSM module serial is spamming messages on the serial port

Tags: pi-zero, gsm

I am using the GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT for raspberry pi zero and after running a simple script

```
import serial   
import os, time
 
# Enable Serial Communication
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
 
# Transmitting AT Commands to the Modem
# '\r\n' indicates the Enter key
 
port.write('AT'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.read(10)
print rcv
```

this outputs for me AT and then OK but sometimes different unexpected characters are shown so I decided to use minicom to figure out whats going on and the moment I connect with minicom the GSM module starts sending random characters. Is that a hardware fault or is it possible to be serial configuration fault ?
[image: When i type AT it repeats each character twice]

Update 1:
After disabling serial console thanks to @dougie's commentit stopped spamming characters but the moment I type something the character is repeated. but this was solved when i sed a python script instead of typing.

Comment: Have you disabled the "serial console" in `sudo raspi-config` or with the GUI preferences dialog?

Comment: No I enabled it. @Dougie

Comment: Disable the "serial console" (which shows up as `console=ttyAMA0,115200` in a `cat /proc/cmdline` command).

Comment: In `cat /proc/cmdline` there is`console=ttyl` how do i disable the serial console from there ? I used `sudo raspi-config` -> Interfacing options -> Serial -> enable, should I disable this ? @Dougie

Comment: I disabled the serial console my output can be shown in the updated post.

Comment: @Dougie if u can submit disabling serial console as an answer I will verify its the correct answer thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the "serial console" (which shows up as `console=ttyAMA0,115200` in a `cat /proc/cmdline` command).